# Why tailwindcss support does not work in PhpStorm 2019.3.4?

Tags: phpstorm, tailwind-css

In PhpStorm 2019.3.4 I work with tailwindcss 2 In laravel 8 app and I installed tailwindcss plugins
I found : Tailwind Formatter, Tailwind CSS Smart Completions, Tailwind Intellisense
But I do not see any tailwindcss support in my PhpStorm in many cases when I need it. In blade.php file having line like

```
  ... 
  <div class="my-2 w-100 admin_content_text_color">
</div>
  ...
```

adding “ px” in end of class definitions I want to see autocomplete hint on existing tailwind
classes

Simialr in my custom resources/css/app.css

```
.editor_form_inactive_tab {
    @apply text-gray-400y;
}
```

entering “text-red-” I do not see any autocomplete hint I expect.
In my webpack.mix.js I have :

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require("tailwindcss"),
    ]);
```

Seems none of installed plagins I wrote above nned any additive options in setting ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Official Tailwind support has been introduced in PhpStorm 2020.3 (see https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2020/11/webstorm-2020-3/), you can't expect it to work in v.2020.2. Please consider upgrading